# Select query to show timestamp (HH:MM:SS) colomn with group by HH (ORACLE QUERY)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create select query in oracle to get following result from my_table

table contents timestamp_coloumn and count coloumn, records in timestamp_colomn are getting inserted are by minute bases.

Tried query:-  something like this

```
 select to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24:MI:SS') as TS , count as count 
 from my_table 
 group by to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24');
```

Error:-

> ```
> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
> ```

if ,I match select and and group by statement like following it works but, i couldn't achieve my expected result (i dont know if is right to query like that)

```
select to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24:MI:SS') as TS , count as count 
from my_table 
group by to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24:MI:SS');
```

Expected result (Hourly timestamp and count is grouped and summed for all records present in that hour):-

```
timestamp_coloumn  count  
--------------------------  
07:01:23             4
08:01:36             3
09:01:44             6
10:01:10             5
```

Please help me with this query

Comment: Your posted desired result does not match your description.

Comment: If there are four records between 07:01:23 and 07:59:59; which timestamp you will show?

Comment: 07:01:23 starting timestamp entry of hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MIN()`:

```
 select min(to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24:MI:SS')) as TS, count(*) 
 from my_table 
 group by to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24');
```

Or make the two expressions match:

```
 select to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24') as TS, count(*) 
 from my_table 
 group by to_char(timestamp_coloumn ,'HH24');
```